# Mysql query logic to list sellers from Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list Sellers with following logic calculation, "List sellers who has 0 purchase in last 15 days and more than 10 purchases in last 2 months"

Here is my query i know something wrong in this query so i need help to fix.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT c.* FROM sellers c
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM orders
            WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW()
        ) d ON c.seller_id = d.seller_id
        GROUP BY c.seller_id
        HAVING count(d.order_id) >= 10
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT c.* FROM sellers c 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW()
        ) as d
        ON c.seller_id = d.seller_id
    WHERE d.seller_id IS NULL)
) derived
```

Comment: **`"List sellers who has 0 purchase in last 15 days and more than 10 purchases in last 2 months"`** Is this condition for the same user?

Comment: sorry, can't understand your question. these condition for sellers (multiple user and result will display at admin level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below mentioned query can be used

```
SELECT c.* FROM sellers c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM orders
        WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND NOW()
    ) d ON c.seller_id = d.seller_id
    GROUP BY c.seller_id
    HAVING count(d.order_id) >= 10
    and c.seller_id in ((SELECT c.seller_id FROM sellers c 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN DATE(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND NOW()
    ) as d
    ON c.seller_id = d.seller_id
WHERE d.seller_id IS NULL))
```

since your current query is fetching data for last 15 days combined with last 2 month

Comment: With above query i receive 0 result

Comment: Please confirm if you've any result which has more or equal to 10 results in last 2 months while no result in last 15 days, I replicated the same with 1 result and it seems to bring the correct result.

Comment: created an example for same. check http://rextester.com/NMSIE5489 Please let me know if you're able to replicate the zero results by modifying the data.

Comment: Thank you, Code work likes what i need but i want to make sure the method is matching with my live results and i prefer the simple one.

Answer (score 0):

With subqueries you can do:

```
select * from tsellers s
where 
    (select count(1) from torders o 
         where 
             o.seller_id=s.id and 
             order_date>DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ) < 1 and
    (select count(1) from torders o 
         where 
             o.seller_id=s.id and 
             order_date>DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) > 10;
```

The subqueries

```
(select count(1) from torders o 
     where 
         o.seller_id=s.id and 
         order_date>DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) )
```

mean: How many orders are related with this seller in the given amount of time

You can test it on [rextester](http://rextester.com/FFPX90593)

Comment: Sorry - you wanted more then 10 purchases in the last 2 month - i fixed it and added some explanation. I hope it is easier to understand now

Comment: Thank you code works like perfect, i will check with my live result and update you soon.